# Graphics painting strategy(performance)

Tags: java, graphics

In my game I have a gamepanel which draws my map layers: 'ground/buildings/objects layer', then player sprite, then enemies/npcs/mobs, then 'above layer(tiles to draw above player)'.  This was working great and running smoothly.

I then started to work on a minimap JInternalFrame.  It actually looks great for what I need but I am concerned with performance.  After adding the minimap I noted some slowdown of painting.  My biggest resolution supports a map of:

```
else if (scrnsize.width >= 1440 && scrnsize.height >= 1024){ //large&wide
    //45x29(32x32px tiles)
    //1440, 1024
```

Basically my question is, is there a better way I can do this(than below code) or methods I can call for offscreen buffer or something?

This is the Minimap code.  As you can see I have logic in the paintComponent to not redraw unless the refreshMinimap == true(the player moves or dies).  This helped get rid of most noticable lag, but I still am noticing some.  Any help would be super appreciated.

```
public MinimapGamePanel() {
    super();
    logger.addAppender(GUILog4JFileHelper.fileAppender);
    gamePanelImage = new BufferedImage(32 * MyClient.xTiles, 32 * MyClient.yTiles, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    logger.trace("begin: REPAINTNG...");
    g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    //map

    if (refreshMinimap){
        RefreshMinimap();
        refreshMinimap = false;
    }
    g2.drawImage(gamePanelImage, 0, 0, null);

    g2.dispose();

    logger.trace("end: REPAINTNG...");
}

private void RefreshMinimap() {
    logger.trace("Map drawing started.");
    int count = (int) ((MyClient.characterX - (MyClient.xTiles*1.5)) + ((MyClient.characterY - (MyClient.yTiles*2)) * MyClient.mapWidth));
    for (int x = 0; x < MyClient.xTiles*3; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < MyClient.yTiles*4; y++){
            if (count > -1  && count < (MyClient.mapWidth * MyClient.mapHeight)){
                if (!MyClient.groundLayer[count].equals("0")){ //don't draw full transparent tiles
                    //SpriteStore.get().getSprite("images/tiles/" + MyClient.groundLayer[count] + ".png").draw(gamePanelImage, x, y);
                    SpriteStore.get().getSprite("images/tiles/" + MyClient.groundLayer[count] + ".png").drawFirstPixel(gamePanelImage, x, y);   
                }
                if (!MyClient.buildingLayer[count].equals("0")){ //don't draw full transparent tiles
                    SpriteStore.get().getSprite("images/tiles/" + MyClient.buildingLayer[count] + ".png").drawFirstPixel(gamePanelImage, x, y);
                }
                if (!MyClient.objectLayer[count].equals("0")){ //don't draw full transparent tiles
                    SpriteStore.get().getSprite("images/tiles/" + MyClient.objectLayer[count] + ".png").drawFirstPixel(gamePanelImage, x, y);
                }
            } else {
                SpriteStore.get().getSprite("images/tiles/" + MyClient.groundLayer[0] + ".png").drawFirstPixel(gamePanelImage, x, y);
            }
            count += MyClient.mapWidth;
        }
        count -= MyClient.yTiles * 4 * MyClient.mapWidth;
        count++;
    }
    logger.trace("Map drawing done.");
}
```

This is the drawing code which just draws pixel 0,0

```
public void drawFirstPixel(BufferedImage gamePanelImage, int xDraw, int yDraw) {
    BufferedImage bufferedVersion = (BufferedImage) image;
    gamePanelImage.getGraphics().drawImage(bufferedVersion.getSubimage(0, 0, 1, 1), xDraw, yDraw, null);    
}
```

I am actually pretty happy with the look of just taking pixel 0,0.  Apologies for the bad quality, shaky cell phone pic.

[image]

Comment: Put your minimap in a separate JFrame on another thread.

Comment: Oh thats a really good idea... you would think making a mmorpg and dealing in threads on the server I would think to utilize one on the client side... lol nope.  Anything else you think could help?  Is my logic sound?

Comment: `Put your minimap in a separate JFrame on another thread` - an application should only have a single main JFrame. Use a JDialog for a child window.

Comment: @camickr thanks for the clarification... right now my GUI is Frame -> JDesktopPane... then I add my JInternalFrames with... theDesktop.add(minimapFrame, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);  Is this an okay strategy?

Comment: that's fine to use a JInternalFrame although you just add the internal frame directly to the desktop pane. I'm not sure why you are referencing the DEFAULT_LAYER. Read the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Internal Frames` for a working example.

Comment: @camickr I do it because in other places I need to paint a dragged image when I click and drag item from ground to players backpack for example: theDesktop.add(dragJLabel, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);... can you take a look at my answer and let me know if that is what you meant by drawing in thread?  Thanks a million for all of your help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this in tune to what you guys were suggesting I do?

```
public class MinimapGamePanel extends JPanel {
    ...
    private static Thread t;

    public MinimapGamePanel() {
        super();
        logger.addAppender(GUILog4JFileHelper.fileAppender);
        gamePanelImage = new BufferedImage(320, 320, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        //TODO:: change values above upon picking minimap size
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        t = new Thread(new RefreshMinimapThread());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        logger.trace("begin: REPAINTNG...");
        g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        if (refreshMinimap){

            t.start();
            //RefreshMinimap();
            refreshMinimap = false;
        }
        g2.drawImage(gamePanelImage, 0, 0, null);

        g2.dispose();

        logger.trace("end: REPAINTNG...");
    }

    private class RefreshMinimapThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            RefreshMinimap();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your MiniMap is a separate component. You should not be attempting to control the painting of that component from within your painting method. Where every your code is the invokes repaint() on you game pane is where you should be doing the repaint in your mini panel as well. Ulitmately all painting of all components gets done on the Event Dispatch Thread. You use a separate Thread when you have a lot of CPU intensive processing to handle your game logic. Then you invoke repaint() and the painting request get placed back onto the EDT.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply.  I will re-read this a few more times until it makes sense.  I am confused where I am not doing what you are saying.  I am running the RefreshMinimap() method in a thread now - it is the cpu intensive task.  I will continue to hack my way through this.  I'm going to do some printing to check times.  Thanks again for all of the help.  Really do appreciate it!

Comment: `I am running the RefreshMinimap() method in a thread now`, you are invoking the Thread from the paintComponent() method. It should not be done from there.

Answer (score 4):

> After adding the minimap I noted some slowdown of painting

```
SpriteStore.get().getSprite("images/tiles/" + MyClient.buildingLayer
```

Don't do I/O in a painting method. All images should be read into memory when you create your class.

Comment: Yeah my SpriteStore class saves the images in memory... I preload them in the beginning: for (int count = 0; count <= (SpriteSheetCutter.cols * SpriteSheetCutter.rows); count ++){
   SpriteStore.get().getSprite("images/tiles/" + count + ".png"); //Preload Map Images
  }

Comment: public Sprite getSprite(String ref) {
  // if we've already got the sprite in the cache
  // then just return the existing version

  if (sprites.get(ref) != null) {
   return (Sprite) sprites.get(ref);
  }